# Springboot database URL change during integration testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, profile, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I am doing integration testing, and have 2 databases to test my project against. Rather than creating 2 profiles, is there a quick and easy way where I create 2 integration test classes, and one to test against the database originally written on my main profile, and another where I add some sort of annotation that changes the database url programatically, but otherwise keeps everything else the same, and run my tests through there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add separate properties file in your test resources then on your second integration test class use annotation `@PropertySource`.

Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html for details

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `properties` argument of `SpringBootTest`, to override specific properties. For example:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "spring.datasource.url=URL_TO_TEST_DB", "spring.datasource.username=Test"})
public class TestIT {
    //...
}
```